# Is there any way of making the shortcut Meta + Arrows work for resizing windows on LXQt 0.14.1?

Tags: lxqt

I've installed [OSGeoLive 14](https://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html) inside a virtual machine. It uses LXQt as its graphical interface, but it bothers me that the shortcuts <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> don't work on it. I'd like to do something like the following:

[image]

In this case, I used a different Virtual machine where the command <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> works fine. Is there any way of configuring this shortcut on LXQt when it's deactivated for some reason? I just want to be able to resize my windows vertically after opening them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use the shortcut functionality as I wanted, but I only partially solved this issue since I didn't manage to make it work with the Meta key. Basically, I've edited the file `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` and added the following text in it:

```
<keybind key="S-Left">                                                                         
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>                                                              
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">                                                                 
    <x>0</x>                                                                                   
    <y>0</y>                                                                                   
    <height>100%</height>                                                                      
    <width>50%</width>                                                                         
  </action>                                                                                    
</keybind>                                                                                     
<keybind key="S-Right">                                                                        
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>                                                              
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">                                                                 
    <x>-0</x>                                                                                  
    <y>0</y>                                                                                   
    <height>100%</height>                                                                      
    <width>50%</width>                                                                         
  </action>                                                                                    
</keybind>
```

With this text added, it works after restarting openbox with `openbox --restart`. This will resize the windows as I wanted after pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.

What didn't work as I expected is that it's working with the `Shift` key instead of the `Meta` key. Even though on the [openbox documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) it's said that we can use the Meta key with `M`, `W` or `0x85` (which is its hexadecimal representation), I didn't manage to make it work with the `Meta` key... I'm not sure if it's because I'm inside a VirtualBox machine. But since it works with the `Shift` key this issue is solved for me.